# Android : Displaying information in two columns instead of one for BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, adapter

I am working on an Android-application in which I am have a java.util.List of Note object which I am displaying on one page by extending BaseAdapter. I have size on the screen to display 2 of them side-by-side.

I don't know how to accomplish this task by using BaseAdapter. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)
As you can see from image below, I have space to display one more column and clickable(which they are right now, to get their ID):

[image: Notes image]

GroupSectionActivity : // Notes retrieval :

```
public class GroupSectionActivity extends DrawerLoader {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sectionlayout);
 final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restSectionArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (RestNote restNote : restNoteListFinal) {
            HashMap<String, String> sectionDisplay = new HashMap<>();
            sectionDisplay.put(noteId, String.valueOf(restNote.getMnoticesid()));
            sectionDisplay.put(noteTag, restNote.getMnotetag());
            sectionDisplay.put(noteText,restNote.getMnotetext());
            sectionDisplay.put(noteColor,restNote.getMnotecolor());
            restSectionArrayList.add(sectionDisplay);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.seclist);

       SectionLazyAdapter sectionLazyAdapter = new SectionLazyAdapter(this, restSectionArrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(sectionLazyAdapter);
}
```

SectionLazyAdapter :

```
public class SectionLazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public SectionLazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_group_section, null);

        TextView noteTag = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.noteTag);
        TextView noteText = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        ImageView noteImage = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.noteImage);
        HashMap<String, String> sectionList = new HashMap<>();
        sectionList = data.get(position);
        noteTag.setText(sectionList.get(GroupSectionActivity.noteTag));
        noteText.setText(sectionList.get(GroupSectionActivity.noteText));
        String noteColorFromList = sectionList.get(GroupSectionActivity.noteColor);
        if(noteColorFromList.equals("#1abc9c")){
            noteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.notegreen);
        }
        if(noteColorFromList.equals("#3498db")){
            noteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.noteblue);
        }
// And other if conditions
return vi;
   }
}
```

sectionLayout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/seclist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sectionAddButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Section"
            android:id="@+id/sectionAddButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sectionNameTextField"
            android:layout_above="@+id/seclist"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sectionAddButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_groupSection.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/noteImage"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noteTag"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="97dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:id="@+id/noteText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what about using `GridView` instead of `ListView` and set `numColumns` to `2`

Comment: just use recyclerview which can be better https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html  which provide all type like grid ,staggered and list

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi : Can you tell me how I can I modify this code to use GridView?

Comment: @Pavan : I don't have any know how about recycler-view. Can you tell me what I should modify in this code to use RecyclerView.

Comment: in your xml file replace `ListView` with `GridView` and set `android:numColumns` to `2` and in java file replace `ListView` with `GridView`

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi : Cool. That worked. Thanks a lot man. If you can make an answer, I will accept it. Also, can you please check this question, I am having problem with Font-awesome(2nd part as mentioned in question). Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041437/android-get-id-of-the-object-which-is-clicked-in-side-bar

Comment: great that worked, i will post an answer and yes i will check after a while hope you dont mind as i am busy with some stuff

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi : Sure. No issues. ty.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve two columns you can use `GridView` instead of `ListView` and set the number of columns to `2` in the `xml` file.

and yes also replace the same in your java file, and set your `adapter` to `GridView` and you are done.

Comment: Please check the question when you have time. Thanks. :-)

Comment: hello @borg sorry, i didnt get the question exactly about font-awesome can you explain a bit more /\

Comment: Sure. Font-awesome are a type of font-set which look more like pictures. Simple 2d images(saved as fonts) like a heart, egg, etc. So, if you save the String 'egg', there will be a 2d image(font) associated with it. So, For my application, I already have saved them and retrieving it in Android. I just want to know how to display those font-awesome fonts. It's a very popular library, you might find references for Android, I dont know much about it, so couldnt make sense.

Comment: can you have a look here https://github.com/aasdkl/font-awsome-for-android and read the **How to** section

Comment: I will take a look and if there are any problems, I will leave a comment here. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: sure and in case it works than post for that also :D